# React useState Flow? will it wait to run below logic or change the state and rerender

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

Here on line 5 I am using react useState setter function to set a value. My code works perfectly fine without errors, but i wanted to know one thing as set state updates the state and as soon as state updates the app rerenders. So, here below the setstate there is some logic that react executes every time an input field is changed. So, is it also possible that sometime it may not run the logic because as the state updates the app rerenders. So, before the logic runs the app rerenders.

```
  function handlePhoneOnChange(
    phoneNumber: string,
    country: { countryCode: string }
  ) {
    setPhone(phoneNumber);
    const countryCode = country.countryCode.toLocaleUpperCase();

    const localeWithCountryCode = validator.isMobilePhoneLocales.find((item) =>
      item.includes(countryCode)
    );
    const formattedPhone = phoneNumber.slice(2);

    mobileValidation.current = validator.isMobilePhone(
      formattedPhone,
      localeWithCountryCode
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

To Answer the question, yes there is a way to prevent the logic from running on each render.

the way to do so is by using useEffect Hook.

[Click here](https://www.reactjstutorials.com/react-basics/26/react-useeffect) in order to be directed to the docs which contains an example as well.

Comment: i am asking on line 5 i have a setter function which rerenders the app but why it runs the logic below it

Comment: Oh ok, that's because React is using something called a virtual DOM.
React will compare between the real DOM and the virtual DOM and then will decide what changes has occurred. 
So when you change the state you basically comparing between to objects, it will not affect the flow of your code.
on top of that setting the state is an Asynchronous in order to make this magic happens. 
Try to use this tutorials

React setting state:
https://medium.learnreact.com/setstate-is-asynchronous-52ead919a3f0

JavaScript the weird parts:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bv_5Zv5c-Ts&t=7705s

Comment: hey @SusantPatel, did my answer helped you with your issue?

Answer (score 0):

If your state is changed then component will re-rendered but before it re-render some logic may get executed. But it is possible that your logic may not run as component can get re-render before your logic get executed. To overcome the risk, you can use setter function at the end in your function "handlePhoneOnChange".